# DevExpress - Xtra Reports: Group Header/Sorting can't use an Aggregate Function

Tags: report, grouping, devexpress

I have to use DevExpress's Xtra Reports which is in a third-part app. I have a group header that displays 'State' but grouped by 'Sum(Payment_Amount)' in descending order of the total and not the name of the state (This is a requirement.).

Group Header:  State
Detail: Each item in this State | Payment_Amount
Group Footer:  Sum(Payment_Amount) for this State

Must sort the groups by the Sum(Payment_Amount) in descending order.

Example: if California has the greatest total amount of the payments, it is first and not Wyoming.

How do I include the Sum(Payment_Amount) in the grouped header collection? Can't include the value of the textbox. Not allowed to put an aggregate function in the expression of a calculated field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to include a sum of these values in the data source. The report is actually grouped on these values and not the names.